Different behavior between running excel office script from a button and from code editor directly
I have written some office script to fetch data from server and fill that data to a table in excel.
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
  // Getting People List
  // Clear the table PeopleList
  let peopleListRowCount: number = workbook.getTable('PeopleList').getRowCount();
  if (peopleListRowCount > 0) {
      workbook.getTable('PeopleList').deleteRowsAt(0, peopleListRowCount);
  }
  GetPeopleList().then(data =>{
    data.forEach(item => {
      let tmp_row: string[] = [item['Person'], item['PersonID']];
      workbook.getTable('PeopleList').addRow(-1, tmp_row);
    })
  })
}

async function GetPeopleList() {
    const link = 'url'
    const key = 'key'

    const response = await fetch(link, { method: 'get', headers: new Headers({ 'Conetent-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': key }) });
    const data :string[] = await response.json();
    return data
}

When the code is run, a list of data is extracted and filled to the table. While the end results are different when I run in code editor and by a button.
When I run the code within the code editor, it works fine. The data is filled to the table.
However, when I press 'Add in Workbook' to create a button and press that button to run the code. The result is different. Sometimes the table does not have all the data and sometimes the table is even empty. Although Excel said the code is run succeeded.
I have tried to do it on desktop app and web version but it seems there is no different between them.
Ultimately, I want the end-use click the button and update the table so I need the button works properly.
